# Strange inheriting from "a" element in "figure" to "p" element

Tags: css, inheritance

I have a really weird bug about inheriting in css. p element that is not inside "a" elements block, inheriting "a" element's properties and turning an "a" element strangely.

```js
// !! IMPORTANT README:

// You may add additional external JS and CSS as needed to complete the project, however the current external resource MUST remain in place for the tests to work. BABEL must also be left in place. 

/***********
INSTRUCTIONS:
  - Select the project you would 
    like to complete from the dropdown 
    menu.
  - Click the "RUN TESTS" button to
    run the tests against the blank 
    pen.
  - Click the "TESTS" button to see 
    the individual test cases. 
    (should all be failing at first)
  - Start coding! As you fulfill each
    test case, you will see them go   
    from red to green.
  - As you start to build out your 
    project, when tests are failing, 
    you should get helpful errors 
    along the way!
    ************/

// PLEASE NOTE: Adding global style rules using the * selector, or by adding rules to body {..} or html {..}, or to all elements within body or html, i.e. h1 {..}, has the potential to pollute the test suite's CSS. Try adding: * { color: red }, for a quick example!

// Once you have read the above messages, you can delete all comments.
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto");
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  min-height: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background: #303841;
}
#navbar a {
  padding: 0 6vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: bold calc(20px + 1vw) "Lato";
  color: #f6c90e;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 0 black;
}

.container #welcome-section {
  background: #303841;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container #welcome-section header {
  font-size: calc(20px + 2vw);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  color: #f6c90e;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 0 black;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
.container #welcome-section header p {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.container #welcome-section header h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container #projects {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #3a4750;
}
.container #projects h2 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(20px + 3vw);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 0 black;
}
.container #projects figure {
  width: 35vw;
}
.container #projects figure img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
.container #projects figure a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.container #projects figure figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 0 black;
  font: bold calc(15px + 1vw) "Roboto";
  color: #f6c90e;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #navbar {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  #projects > * {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #projects a {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) and (max-width: 576px) {
  #navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<!-- Navigation bar -->
<nav id="navbar">
 <a href="#welcome-section">About</a>
 <a href="#projects">Work</a>
 <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>

<!-- Main content -->
<main class="container">
 <section id="welcome-section">
  <header>
   <h1>Anıl Emek Türkeli</h1>
   <p>Frontend Developer</p>
  </header>
 </section>
 <section id="projects">
  <h2>All Works I've Done So Far         </h2>
  <figure class="project-tile">
   <a href="https://codepen.io/anilemek/full/VRmXqP" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/12/f3614255ab87606e66bf5d449e194599-full.png"</a>
   <figcaption>Sass Technical Documentation Page</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="project-tile">
   <a href="https://codepen.io/anilemek/full/YgqoLa" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/12/99066cf68f33649bc17562c4925c3afa-full.png"</a>
   <figcaption>Repedo Landing Page</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="project-tile">
   <a href="https://codepen.io/anilemek/full/BMbwXE" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/12/626217cf51607a559f6a47fad499f355-full.png"</a>
   <figcaption>Repedo Survey Form</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="project-tile">
   <a href="https://codepen.io/anilemek/full/OddXaR" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/12/1dbdcffbefc68964500597ec04e48e05-full.png"</a>
   <figcaption>Mustafa Kemal Atatürk's Tribute Page</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </section>
 <section id="contact">
  <p>Deneme</p>
 </section>
</main>
```

https://codepen.io/anilemek/pen/PLjpQm

Can anybody explain why this issue occured?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about the `<p>` with text`Deneme` at the bottom of the site, the issue is in the `img` tags before. You have to close them. So eg,`<img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/12/626217cf51607a559f6a47fad499f355-full.png"/>`